# Can I set the priority of boolean variables in z3?

Tags: z3

Since the question is a little hard to describe, I will use a small example to describe my question.
Suppose there is a propositional formula set whose elements are Boolean variables a,b and c.
When using z3 to get a truth assignment of this formula set, does there exist some way to set the priority of the variables? I mean that if the priority is a>b>c, then during the searching   process z3 firstly assumes a is true and if a is impossible to be true it assumes b is true and so on. In another words, if z3 gives a truth assignment: not a,b,c under the aforementioned priority it means a is impossible to be true because a is high-priority compared with b. Hope I describe the question clearly.

Comment: Perhaps related:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/13921545/87234

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not easy way to do it in the current release (v4.3.1). The only way I can see is to hack/modify the Z3 source code (http://z3.codeplex.com). We agree that setting priorities is a useful feature for some applications, however there are some problems.

First, Z3 applies several transformations (aka preprocessing steps) before solving a problem. Variables are created and eliminated. Thus, a case-split priority for the original problem may be meaningless for the actual problem (the one generated after applying all transformations) that is solved by Z3.

One dramatic example is a formula containing only Bit-vectors. By default, Z3 will reduce this formula into Propositional logic and invoke a Propositional SAT solver. In this reduction, *all* Bit-vector variables are eliminated.

Z3 is a collection of solvers and preprocessors. By default, Z3 will select a solver automatically for the user. Some of these solvers use completely different algorithms. So, the provided priority may be useless for the solver being used.

As [GManNickG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87234/gmannickg) pointed out, it is possible to set the phase selection strategy for a particular solver. See the post provided in his comment for additional details.