# Optimize Solver Tactics for Circuit SAT

Tags: z3, z3py

I am using the `Z3` solver with `Python API` to tackle a [Circuit SAT problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_satisfiability_problem).
It consists of many `Xor` expressions with up to 21 inputs and three-input `And` expressions. `Z3` is able to solve my smaller examples but does not cope with the bigger ones.

Rather than creating the `Solver` object with

```
s = Solver()
```

I tried to optimize the solver tactics like in

```
t = Then('simplify', 'symmetry-reduce', 'aig', 'tseitin-cnf', 'sat' )
s = t.solver()
```

I got the tactics list via `describe_tactics()`

Unfortunately, my attempts have not been fruitful. The default sequence of tactics seems to do a pretty good job. The tactics tutorial previously available in [rise4fun](http://rise4fun.com/z3py/tutorial) is no longer accessible.

Another attempt - without visible effect - was to set the phase parameter, as I am expecting the majority of my variables to have false values. (cf [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921545/z3-polarity-using-z3-as-sat-solver))

```
set_option("sat.phase", "always-false")
```

> What sequence of tactics is recommended for **Circuit SAT** problems?

Comment: There are no "recommended" tactic for this type of problem and I suspect it will depend heavily on what exactly appears in the problem, e.g., large numbers of xor constraints can make things very difficult to solve. Z3py is not available on rise4fun anymore, the the (smt2-) strategies is still available here: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/strategies