# SAT solver set default result(cryptominisat)

Tags: logic, solver, sat

I'm modeling a problem with SAT and trying to solve it with [cryptominisat](https://github.com/msoos/cryptominisat). I'd like to give my variable a default value if there's no constraint for it.

I went through the manual and `set_default_polarity` seems like the answer. I tried it out but it doesn't work as I expected. I don't really get the term `polarity` here. Some googling didn't help me out as I'm not familiar with logic.

So, my questions are:

1. Would you kindly explain what `polarity` is or point me to some introductory-level sources?
2. Is there an interface in cryptominisat(or in SAT solvers generally) to set default value for logic variables? What is the term for such functionality?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`cryptominisat --hhelp` (note the extra `h`!) gives the following extended help:

```
.....
  --polar arg (=auto)                   {true,false,rnd,auto} Selects polarity
                                        mode. 'true' -> selects only positive
                                        polarity when branching. 'false' ->
                                        selects only negative polarity when
                                        brancing. 'auto' -> selects last
                                        polarity used (also called 'caching')
.....
```

I use `--polar=false` to let `cryptominisat` search for solutions with `false/0` variables first, because my examples have most solution variables that way.

In the source, this corresponds to `solverconf.h`:

```
enum class PolarityMode {
    polarmode_pos
    , polarmode_neg
    , polarmode_rnd
    , polarmode_automatic
};
```

The respective `SolverConf` variable is `PolarityMode polarity_mode`

In `main.cpp` is shown how to set this configuration property in a program:

```
if (vm.count("polar")) {
        string mode = vm["polar"].as<string>();

        if (mode == "true") conf.polarity_mode = polarmode_pos;
        else if (mode == "false") conf.polarity_mode = polarmode_neg;
        else if (mode == "rnd") conf.polarity_mode = polarmode_rnd;
        else if (mode == "auto") conf.polarity_mode = polarmode_automatic;
        else throw WrongParam(mode, "unknown polarity-mode");
    }
```

---

Other SAT solvers are using terms like `phase` or `sign`.

[Microsoft Z3](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3) can be parameterized via commandline `sat.phase=always_false` to try `false phase` first. See a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921545/z3-polarity-using-z3-as-sat-solver). Actually, my first question on `StackOverflow` back in 2012.

[Clasp](https://potassco.org/clasp/) is using commandline syntax `--sign-def=neg` to take `false polarity` first.